# I need to create a matrix showing the number of orders made each month of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL, currently working on the **AdventureWorks2019** database.

The results must look like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLDy2.jpg

So far I have this, but I can't figure out how to fill the tables, its all empty:

```sql
select mm as "Month", [1] as '2011', [2] as '2012', [3] as '2013', [4] as '2014'
from(
select year(h.orderdate) as yy, month(h.orderdate) as mm, d.OrderQty
from sales.SalesOrderHeader h join sales.SalesOrderDetail d
on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID) o
pivot(count(OrderQty) for yy in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) piv
order by mm
```

I need to match the result image I posted at the top of this post.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use this if you want to go with the pivot route

```
select mm as "Month", [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014]
from(
select  month(h.orderdate) as mm,year(h.orderdate) as yy, d.OrderQty
from sales.SalesOrderHeader h join sales.SalesOrderDetail d
on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
) o
pivot(count(OrderQty) for yy in ([2011], [2012], [2013], [2014])) piv
order by mm
```

If you don't want to hard code years in the query, you can also go with dynamic sql route

```
with cte as (
select  distinct year(h.orderdate) as yy
from sales.SalesOrderHeader h join sales.SalesOrderDetail d
on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
)

select @years  = SUBSTRING ((select  ',[' + cast (yy as varchar(4)) +']' from cte order by yy for xml path ('')),2,1000) 

set @cmd = 'select mm as "Month", '+@years+'
from(
select  month(h.orderdate) as mm,year(h.orderdate) as yy, d.OrderQty
from sales.SalesOrderHeader h join sales.SalesOrderDetail d
on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
) o
pivot(count(OrderQty) for yy in ('+@years+')) piv
order by mm '

exec sp_executesql @cmd
```

Comment: You're awesome! the pivot method worked, but can you explain why mine didnt work?

Comment: [1] as '2011', [2] as '2012', [3] as '2013', [4] as '2014' is not [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014]. for Pivot to work, you need that corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation.  It is not clear if you want the number of orders or the sum of quantities, but the idea is:

```
select month(h.orderdate) as mont,
       sum(case when year(h.orderdate) = 2011 then 1 else 0 end) as [2011],
       sum(case when year(h.orderdate) = 2012 then 1 else 0 end) as [2012],
       sum(case when year(h.orderdate) = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) as [2013],
       sum(case when year(h.orderdate) = 2014 then 1 else 0 end) as [2014]
from sales.SalesOrderHeader h join
     sales.SalesOrderDetail d
     on h.SalesOrderID = d.SalesOrderID
group by month(h.orderdate)
order by month(h.orderdate);
```